# PyGame Loop with sprite creation in each loop not updating

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, pygame, sprite

I'm creating a physics simulation which simulates the Rutherford scattering experiment. I'm trying to create an alpha particles (sprite) each time the loop is run and I'm able to create it (shows up on screen) but it doesn't move forwards whereas if I create only one particle, it works fine.

I've attached the sprite's class and the loop as to where it's being created.

Loop:

```
while running:
    clock.tick(20)
    allparticles = pygame.sprite.Group(Particle(speed, bwidthmin, bwidthmax, background))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    allparticles.clear(screen, background)
    nucgroup.draw(screen)
    allparticles.update()
    allparticles.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Sprite Class:

```
class Particle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, speed, bwidthmin, bwidthmax, background):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.background = background
    self.image = pygame.Surface((16,16))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    currenty = random.randint(bwidthmin,bwidthmax)
    self.rect.centery = currenty
    self.rect.centerx = 0
    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, yellow, (8,8), 5)

    self.dx=speed
    self.dy = 0
def update(self):
    c1 = (self.rect.centerx,self.rect.centery)
    self.rect.centerx += self.dx
    if self.rect.right >= 570:
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill(self)
    pygame.draw.line(self.background, white, c1, (self.rect.centerx,self.rect.centery), 1)
```

Where am I going wrong?

I also have the issue of my tkinter window in which this pygame is embedded hanging (buttons not pressing, tabs not changing, can't do anything until pygame stops). Is the loops running forever causing this to happen? I'd like to be able to update the variables to affect the simulation during runtime or is that not possible?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are overwriting `allparticles` each time through the loop.  Perhaps you mean to keep creating particles and appending to a list?

Try this:

```
allparticles = []
while running:
    clock.tick(20)
    allparticles.append(pygame.sprite.Group(Particle(speed, bwidthmin, bwidthmax, background)))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for particle in allparticles:  # loop over all particles each time
       particle.clear(screen, background)
       nucgroup.draw(screen)
       particle.update()
       particle.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and it worked great. One other question is how to remove the line the particle leaves behind once it has reached the end? I don't mind it disappearing but I'd like it to fade.